# ERROR RangeError: Invalid array length in angular

Tags: angular

I have angular version 14. I am having this error. When i click Review button, this error is coming and Reviews aren't showing

ERROR RangeError: Invalid array length

[Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIqgv.png)

My Code

```
<div class="emVaRl" *ngIf="rating && total_rating">
   <div class="lnfldP">
      <svg width="16" height="16" class="elJCm" viewBox="0 0 24 24"  *ngFor='let in of counter(rating) ;let i = index'>
<path
d="M16.2 8.16l4.74.73a1.23 1.23 0 01.67 2.11l-3.46 3.28a1.23 1.23 0 00-.37 1.1l.77 4.68a1.24 1.24 0 01-1.82 1.29L12.5 19.1a1.28 1.28 0 00-1.16 0l-4.27 2.17A1.25 1.25 0 015.27 20l.85-4.68a1.19 1.19 0 00-.34-1.09l-3.41-3.4a1.23 1.23 0 01.71-2.1l4.75-.64a1.26 1.26 0 00.95-.67l2.16-4.24a1.25 1.25 0 012.24 0l2.09 4.28a1.22 1.22 0 00.93.7z">
</path>
</svg><span class="emVaRl">({{rating}})</span><span class="emVaRl">({{total_rating}})</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

And

```
  counter(i: number) {
    return new Array(i);
}
```

Review Button

```
<div class="checkbox-item mt-2"  (click)="getReviews(item.offer_by.id)">   
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >Reviews</button>
</div>
```

on these two console is pointing error.

Comment: where is review button?

Comment: <div class="checkbox-item mt-2"  (click)="getReviews(item.offer_by.id)">   
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" >Reviews</button>
                </div>

Comment: Looking at the RANGE ERROR. this seems an exeption as it is.
check this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#exceptions

Comment: The id passed by the counter function must be exceeding (2^32) - 1 or preceeding 0

Comment: Dear Yousaf, i am trying to fix it from hours, but I am not able to do. What is missing or what I need to do make it work?

Comment: Thank you Yousaf. I am a beginner in angular. Just confirming you are saying about this it should be
 counter(i: 1) {
    return new Array(i);
}

Comment: I have put in the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This exception is because the id passed by the counter to `Array(i)` is less than 0 or greater than `(2^32) -1` ie `4294967295`. See [exception](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array#exceptions)

You can put a limit using Math.max and Math.min like this

```
counter(i: number) {
    if (i === NaN) return Array(0);
    return new Array(Math.max(0, Math.min(4294967295, i)); // limit b/w 0 and 4294967295
}
```

**Alternatively**

```
counter(i: number) {
   if ( i < 0 || i === NaN ) return Array(0);
   else if ( i > 4294967295) return Array(4294967295);

   return Array(i);
}
```

Comment: On click of Review button, Tried this, but still same error in console and on same line of numbers as in my question

counter(i: number) {
    if ( i < 0 ) return Array(0);
    else if ( i > 4294967295) return Array(4294967295);
 
    return Array(i);
  }

Comment: Check again I update the code, I think your input is NaN. It also give RANGE ERROR

Comment: Apology Yousaf. Still same with NaN. Need to clear cache of Angular?

Comment: Yousaf possible for AnyDek

Comment: i have sent now.